# How to run daemon within a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, daemon

I'm trying to start a server daemon from within my js code, then to access it from the same program. However, when I use the `execFile()` method from the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) module, this blocks the entire program: the `execFile()` call never stops, and I am unable to access the server. However, I know the daemon is started since I see a process of the same name start up from my activity monitor (macos equivalent of task manager).

I've also tried `exec()` and `spawn()` from the same module, and it gave the same results.

What I'd want to be able to do is to start the daemon as a separate process, forget about it, then stop it when I'm done using it. Is there any way I could do at least the first two?

Here is my code (the `runArduino` function is where I start the daemon, and the `main()` function is where I access it):

```
const grpcLib = require('grpc');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const pathLib = require("path");



const utilLib = require('util');
const exec = utilLib.promisify(require('child_process').execFile);

const RPC_PATH = pathLib.join(__dirname, "arduino-cli/rpc")
var PROTO_PATH = pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/commands.proto");

const options = {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true,
    includeDirs: 
    [
        RPC_PATH
    ]
  }
  
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, options);
const arduinoCli = grpcLib.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).cc.arduino.cli.commands;



function runArduino()
{

    
    exec(__dirname+"/arduino-cli_macos", ['daemon'],function(err, data)
    {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
}

function main()
{
    
    
    var client = new arduinoCli.ArduinoCore('localhost:50051', grpcLib.credentials.createInsecure());


    client.Version({}, function(err, response){
        console.log("Running version: ", response); //returns a version number
    });

    
    
}

runArduino();
main();
```

The first time I run it, this is what I get (execution doesn't stop):

```
Running version:  undefined
```

Once the daemon is up and I run it, I get this (I am able to access the server now and execution does end):

```
Running version:  { version: '0.11.0' }
Error: Command failed: /Users/Herve/Desktop/MyStuff/ArduinoX/ArduinoX/arduino-cli_macos daemon
Failed to listen on TCP port: 50051. Address already in use.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:674:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 5,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/Users/Herve/Desktop/MyStuff/ArduinoX/ArduinoX/arduino-cli_macos daemon'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should either `await` the exec or run `main()` in exec's callback. Right now your `main()` executes before child process is started.

```
exec(__dirname+"/arduino-cli_macos", ['daemon'],function(err, data)
    {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

This is why at the first run you're getting `undefined`. Child process is not killed automatically, I guess, this is why at second run you can do the RPC, but can't really start the child process again, as it's already running (and is occupying the 50051 port).

If your application is starting the child process, I believe it has to take care of killing it as well:

```
var childProcessHandler = exec(__dirname+"/arduino-cli_macos", ['daemon'],function(err, data)
    {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
    });
// ... and later in your code:
childProcessHandler.kill()
```

This way you could start/stop the application without having to worry about cleaning the processes. Only thing which you have to consider is taking care of cleanup in case an exception occurs.

**Edit** okay, it appears that to start process as a daemon, you'd have to use `spaw` with `detached` option:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn(__dirname+"/arduino-cli_macos", {
  detached: true
});

child.unref();
```

Comment: I get what you mean, but when I call ```main()``` in the callback or await for ```exec()``` to return the childprocess, ```main()``` ends up never being called. It seems to me that the exec() call never actually ends, as ```childProcessHandler``` never gets assigned. I don't know if this behaviour is typical of daemons. When I call the arduino-cli_macos daemon command directly on the command line, it doesn't end unless I quit the console, so I think it has to do with that.

Comment: Hmm...where did you get this `daemon` by the way? I cannot see it in the spec anywhere...if you want to pass arguments to your cmd, it has to be in the first argument after a space.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can start and end the daemon properly. Unfortunately, I'm still unable to access to server for whatever reason, but since the scope of my question has been answered, I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: The daemon is run by the arduino-cli binary, when run it's grpc interface is exposed.